# Reading through a txt file and finding words java

Tags: java

I'm trying to develop a program that reads a 7 digit number and corresponds all possible words from a txt file. The numbers on a telephone correspond to 3 letters, i.e. 2 has "A" "B" "C" all the way through 9.

I'm not sure how I can get 2 to correspond to the letters and or search the txt file for the matching words.

Not looking for someone to do my work for me, just suggestions with my code.
Should I implement a search or some sort that uses a txt file?

Thanks in advance.

public class Project2 {

```
    public static void test(String[] args)
    {   
        File file = new File("EnglishWordList.txt");
        /**
         * Gets user input and store it within a string
         */
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a 7 digit phone number: ");
        String string = scan.nextLine();

        /**
         * Checks string for 0's or 1's
         */
        if(string.contains("[^1\\]") || string.contains("[^0\\]"))
        {
            System.out.println(string + " contains a o and or 1.");
            Project2.test(args);
        }

        /**
         * Checks to see if the string is 7 digits
         */
        if(string.length() != 7)
        {
            Project2.test(args);
        }

        /**
         * Checks string length, if 7 read through txt file
         */
        if(string.length() == 7)
        {
            try {
                Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
                while(in.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String line = in.nextLine();
                    if(line.indexOf(string) != -1)
                    {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                }
                in.close();
            }   catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("File not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not clear . state thequestion clearly? what do you want to do

Comment: Do you mean each digit should be mapped to its [E.161 letters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.161) and then you want to find all possible 7-letter words that match that telephone number in your text file?

Comment: @MeshBoy I'm trying to get my program to read through a txt file and match ALL possible words with the digits entered. For instance, if the 7digit number I entered has all 2's in it and the letters on a phone that correspond with two, are normally "A" "B" and "C," one of the word that would be printed is "CAB" for instance. I have a txt file with all these words btw and I'm looking for a way to scan the file for possible matches to words and print them. It's hard to explain but I think I did okay with that.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I responded to the user above. Hopefully that answers the question you asked as well.

Comment: It doesn't, because I asked you about a specific standard where it's clear what to do with most numbers (except 1 and 0), and you haven't answered that.

Comment: Is it possible for me to do a MAP and a SWITCH?

Comment: Maybe build a regex pattern from the digits: 2 is `[abc]`, 3 is `[def]`, and so on, and match the words against that regex

Comment: @RealSkeptic I literally just explain all other numbers have a bout 3 or 4 numbers assigned to them and after and from the combination of 7 digits, all possible words from a txt file would be printed. I can't be any simpler in explanation than this honestly.

Comment: @ClemensKlein-Robbenhaar Sounds like a plan I'll go with. Thank you.